# Official proof (document) that Linux is safer and faster than Windows

Tags: linux, proxy, government, windows-8

I work for the Mexican government, and even though everyone involved in Linux knows that it is safer and runs faster in most instances, I have not found an official document or authority that I can show to my superiors. The need for this document is bureaucratic. I need to use the proxy of my local LAN, and need to convince the internal officials of the need that I have for using Linux, instead of the Windows that they officially use and for which they are convinced they have to pay a license for.

Any solid ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is opinion, and therefore no such document will exist.

Comment: "[E]veryone involved in Linux knows that it is safer and runs faster in most instances". Don't speak for everyone... Certainly Linux is not faster if you ever need to use PowerPoint or Word. "[I]nstead of the Windows that they officially use and for which they are convinced they have to pay a license for." They do have to "pay a license for" Windows; it is proprietary software.

Comment: @hft I think there might be a language quirk there: "convinced they have to pay a licence for" could also mean that they are convinced they they must always pay to obtain the ability to use an OS (which is not the case for Linux).

Comment: Ah yeah, I think you could be right

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a document like that because it is highly dependent on its application, its configuration, and its use. Linux has more configuration options which *can* make it faster and safer (whatever that might mean in your context), but those options also mean that it can be slower and more dangerous.

If there was an "official document", then every government and every major corporation would use it as the basis for everyone switching to Linux over Windows.